# Iterating on my array in JS but I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to build a simple zip code checker where the program will check a user's input zip code matches a list of valid zip codes. The issue is, I am running into an error that says "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```js
let validZips = [12345, 78910];
let zip = document.getElementById("zipCode").value;

const checkCode = (zip, validZips) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < validZips.length; i++) {

    if (zip !== validZips[i]) {
      alert("out of service area")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="zipCode">Zip Code</label> <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a zipcode" id="zipCode"> <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="checkCode()"> Check Zip Code</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If your zip codes are all number, performing binary search would be more efficient (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-in-javascript/)

Comment: will give this a shot but I'd really like to understand why my current code block is giving me an error.

Comment: @Anakin the question is about getting a for-loop to work. Your link probably isn’t super relevant.

Comment: @1252748 That's exactly why I added it as a comment

Comment: You added it because it was irrelevant. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

validZips.length works fine, check this out

```js
let validZips = [12345, 78910];

const checkCode = (zip, validZips) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < validZips.length; i++) {
    if (zip !== validZips[i]) {
      console.log("out of service area, ", validZips[i]);
    }
  }
}

checkCode(1234, validZips);
```

Comment: The only difference between your code and mine is the declaration of the "zip" variable and the use of console.log vs alert but I am still getting the same "cannot read property 'length'..." error in my console.

Comment: @kobyrthr I have run this and can confirm it works. It’s possible you aren’t passing the array into your function so the outer `validZips` is being overwritten by the the argument set in the function’s scope.

Comment: That's it! I defined the array within the function and the code executed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

User "barzin.A" suggested that the code wasn't executing because the array wasn't in the function scope. I defined the array in the scope of the function and everything worked as intended. Here's the solution code:

```
let zip = document.getElementById("zipCode").value;

 const checkCode = (validZips,zip) =>

 {
    validZips = [12345,67891];
     for(let i=0; i < validZips.length; i++){

     if (zip !== validZips[i]) {
         alert("out of service area")
     }
 }
```